# Spawn object after AR recognition

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, instantiation

I am developing a augmented reality application that download asset bundle from the web and instantiate different object depending on the image target. What I am trying to do is to not automatically spawn the object but rather "pause" the script and wait for a button to be clicked by the user in order to spawn the object.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far (code)? If you can detect an image and spawn something right away, it should not be difficult to do something else instead that causes the spawning to occur later, but that depends on what you have already.

Comment: Yes sure. I've got the logic down but I am fairly new to Unity and I am not sure how to implement this feature.

Here is a snippet of the code:

What I have so far is the follwing:

public void OnFound() {
....
StartCoroutine(WaitForReq());
...
}

IEnumerator WaitForReq() {
//Asset bundle is downloaded and instantiated automatically
}

When an image target is found the onFound function triggers the coroutine, which on the other hand waits for the assetbundle to be downloaded and instantiated. What I am looking for is to interrupt the process and instantiate the object on click.

Comment: please edit your question with the code you have. In a comment it is not readable.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the previous answer. Here is a snippet of the code.

When the user scans a particular target, the app has to display (spawn) an object onto it. Currently the app does this automatically without any user interaction. What I am looking for is to interupt the spawning process after the bundle is downloaded.

```
public void OnFound() {
    Debug.Log("[EasyAR] OnFound targtet name: " + target.name());
    StartCoroutine(WaitForReq());
}

IEnumerator WaitForReq() {

    while (!Caching.ready)
        yield return null;

    WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(url, version);

    yield return www;

    bundle = www.assetBundle;

    clone = Instantiate(bundle.LoadAsset(model)) as GameObject;
}
```

What I was thinking of is to have an if statement before the models is instantiated in order to interrupt the process, but i am not sure how to implement it.

Hope that clears things out.